# Tkinter entry widget wont take input when using notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to get input from an entry widget using Python Tkinter using Notebook. I have managed to get it to work on my main canvas but as soon as I introduced tabs, it would not work. I am clearly missing something linking the .get function to the correct location but I can't work out what. Any ideas?

```
import tkinter 
import win32api
from tkinter import ttk 

checklist = tkinter.Tk()

checklist.title("My Checklist")
ScreenWidth=checklist.winfo_screenwidth()
ScreenHeight=checklist.winfo_screenheight()
checklist.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight))

count = 0
tasks = []

tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(checklist, width = 500, height = 500)
tab = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
tabcontrol.add(tab, text = "Checklist Home Page")
tabcontrol.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

main_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(checklist, width = 1000, height = 1000, highlightbackground="green")
main_canvas.grid(row=1, column = 0)
main_canvas.columnconfigure(3)
main_canvas.rowconfigure(6)

def create_checklist():
        global count
        count += 1
        if count > 10:
            win32api.MessageBox(0, 'Maximum number of checklists made!')
        else:
            tab = ttk.Frame(checklist, width = 500, height = 500)
            tabcontrol.add(tab, text = count)
            tabcontrol.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
            button_add_task = tkinter.Button(tab, text="Add task", width=20, height=1, bg="purple", command=add_task).grid(row = 2, column= 2, pady = (100, 1))
            item_entry = tkinter.Entry(tab).grid(row=6, column =2)    
            list_items = tkinter.Listbox(tab)
            list_items.grid(row =7, column =2, pady=10)

def add_task():
    task = item_entry.get()
    if task !="":
        tasks.append('- ' + task)
        update_listbox()

button_create_checklist = tkinter.Button(main_canvas, text="New Checklist", width=20, height=1, bg = "purple", command=create_checklist).grid(row = 3, column = 2, pady = 1 )

checklist.mainloop()
```

My error is currently:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\OneDrive\Documents\Employability\untitled0999py.py", line 40, in add_task
    task = item_entry.get()
NameError: name 'item_entry' is not defined
```

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `item_entry` is local variable of function `create checklist()`, it can't be used in `add_task()` function. So, we'll pass value of `Entry` field whenever `Add Task` button is pressed. To do so, we can use lambda expression in `command` option of `Button`. There are some minor changes in `add_task()` function.

**Remember:** `grid` is used to organize widgets and it returns **None**, so `item_entry` will be a `NoneType` object in your code and using `get()` with it will raise `AttributeError`.
So, we need to replace

```
item_entry = tkinter.Entry(tab).grid(row=6, column =2)
```

with

```
item_entry = tkinter.Entry(master=tab)    
item_entry.grid(row=6, column =2)
```

**This code works Fine:**

```
def create_checklist():
        global count
        count += 1
        if count > 10:
           win32api.MessageBox(0, 'Maximum number of checklists made!')
        else:
            tab = ttk.Frame(checklist, width = 500, height = 500)
            tabcontrol.add(tab, text = count)
            tabcontrol.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
            item_entry = tkinter.Entry(master=tab)    # Changes in
            item_entry.grid(row=6, column =2)         # these lines
            button_add_task = tkinter.Button(tab, text="Add task", width=20, height=1, bg="purple", command=lambda :add_task(item_entry.get())).grid(row = 2, column= 2, pady = (100, 1))
            list_items = tkinter.Listbox(tab)
            list_items.grid(row =7, column =2, pady=10)


def add_task(task):
    if task !="":
        tasks.append('- ' + task)
        update_listbox()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great help. Just a small follow up question. For the next step i need to update my list box. Would I use the lambda expression, in the same way, to pass task to the update_listbox function?

Comment: You really don't need to do that. In tkinter, we generally use lambda expression with `command` option which is used to bind a function with an event. But to pass task to your `update_listbox` function, you are not pressing any button or doing something like that. So you can simply pass `task` to it. But before doing so, don't forget to make Listbox global. Thanks.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Ive managed to pass the correct arguments now. Im just struggling to make listbox global. Is this done in the same way that you would make a global variable? Thanks again.

Comment: Do this in the same way you've made your `count` variable global. Just add `list_items` in the first line of your `create_checklist` function. After doing this, first line of that function should look like: `global count, list_items`

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Thank you so much for your quick and helpful responses!